# Passing a 2D array as a double pointer in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

How would I go about passing a 2D array to the following function

```
arrayInput(char **inputArray)
```

and then be able to access the array using standard 2D array syntax

```
inputArray[][]
```

Specifically, I need to be able to call `atoi(inpuArray[0])` to convert an array of characters to an int. I know that this in not the best way, but it is a project requirement to make it work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it would not be a 2D array of `char`, but an array of char* pointers. Like this:

```
void arrayInput(char **inputArray) {
    printf("%s\n", inputArray[0]);
    printf("%s\n", inputArray[1]);
}

int main() {
    char* strings[] = { "hello", "world" };
    arrayInput(strings);
}
```

The type of `strings` is of type `char*[]` (array of pointer to char), which decays to `char**` (pointer to pointer to char).

--

For a true 2D array, where the rows are concatenated in the same memory buffer, the dimension of the second row needs to be part of the type. For example

```
void arrayInput(int mat[][2]) {
    printf("%d %d\n", mat[0][0], mat[0][1]);
    printf("%d %d\n", mat[1][0], mat[1][1]);
}

int main() {
    int mat[][2] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
    arrayInput(mat);
}
```

Here `mat` is of type `int[2][2]`, which decays to `int[][2]` (array of array of 2 int) and `int(*)[2]` (pointer to array of 2 int).

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The 'arrayInput' function takes a pointer to array of pointers. This is different than the 2D array, which is array of array of chars. Assuming that you must keep the prototypes and the data definition, you can create an array of points to match the prototype. However, you will need to know the actual dimensions of inputArray (sample code assumed N, M). Also, the code assume that each element of inputArray is nul terminated.

```
// Caller Function
// N, M are needed.
    char inputArray[N][M] ;
// Fill inputArray

    // Temporary array, holding pointer to each element
    char *p[N] ;
    for (int i=0 ; i<N ; i++ ) p[i] = inputArray[i] ;
    arrayInput(p) ;
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!